# jQuery multiple show hides in one form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a number of questions on it, some are a yes/no. If yes is selected, it will display a text box asking for more info. I've got the show/hide part to work but once I click a button elsewhere on the page it then hides the textarea and i lose the info.

Currently I'm using this:
JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".text").hide();
$("#r1").click(function () {
    $(".text").show();
});
$("#r2").click(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
});
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" value="Yes">
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" value="No">
<div class="text">
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on your code http://jsfiddle.net/0d51tsem/ - is anything wrong there?

Comment: Maybe your another button id name is same. Id name must be different. Have a look at the button that you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the textarea relative to the checkboxes being checked.

- I've listened for the `change` event, rather than `click` (there are other ways of changing a radio button other than clicking it)
- I've used `.nextAll()` and `.first()` to get the relevant textarea
- I've also used `toggle()` with `this.value == 'Yes'` which will be expressed as a true or false value and therefore show or hide the element respectively.

```
$('.text').hide();
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.text').first().toggle( this.value == 'Yes' );
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo7f4Lyj/1/)

Comment: Thanks for answering - if I wanted to change from a radio button to a normal button - what modifications would I need to make to your Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

OP here, if anyone is looking for the answer using buttons instead I resolved the issue with advice from  Norlihazmey Ghazali who mentioned to target the specific id. 
For example:

```
            <div class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="taxliabl1" value="Yes"></input>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="taxliabl2" value="No"></input>
                <br>
                <div class="taxliabltext">
                <br>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
                <br>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".taxliabltext").hide();
   $("#taxliabl1").click(function () {
   $(".taxliabltext").show();
   });
   $("#taxliabl2").click(function () {
   $(".taxliabltext").hide();
   });
});
```